# Adding coremetrics to an iphone ipad app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, web-analytics-tools

Has anyone tried integrating IBM's [Coremetrics](http://www.coremetrics.com/) into an iOS app?  I am looking at adding analytics to a customer's app.  They currently use Coremetrics for their website, and I've used Flurry.

Comment: Your customer should have free access to help from Coremetrics Support, which includes a SDK for iOS and accompanying documentation. Or do you have that and are looking for more guidance?

Answer (score 0):

Adding IBM coremetrics from an iPhone / iPad is not too difficult.

Its just making http call to coremetric server (http://testdata.coremetrics.com - test server) with your coremetrics client ID. You may need to follow the steps below for enabling coremetrics tagging in your iPhone app.

- Create an account in the IBM coremetrics server. Then you will be
  provided witha Client ID, Username and password.
- Add Coremetrics iOS library from IBM to your project. It will be few
  source files that you need to add to your source folder. This you can get it by contating IBM coremetrics support team cm_support@us.ibm.com
- Give your client ID in the appropriate place in the URL.
- Then make an http connection to the coremetrics server, by calling appropriate function from the library files that you added to your project.

Once you have done this login to https://itt.coremetrics.com and check if your entry has been logged.

Hope it help!